# Getting the "videoId" from a YouTube video using YouTubeV3-API

Tags: python, http, python-requests, youtube-api

As the title suggests I am trying to get the "videoId" from a YouTube video.

Currently this is my code, it can be replicated.

```
import requests

channel_id = "UCfjTZZ3iqy24oSg-bmi2waw"
api_key = ""

api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channel_id}&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={api_key}"

request = requests.get(api_url).text


print(request)
```

When doing this method it returns me this:
[result from requests.get(api_url).text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ8WH.png)

If I were to do this

> print(request["videoId"])

It would return me this

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Am I just doing it wrong? Even if I try requesting a higher key it returns the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the received JSON and to precise the path of the entry you are looking for, see the code below:

```py
import requests, json

channel_id = "UCfjTZZ3iqy24oSg-bmi2waw"
api_key = ""

api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channel_id}&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={api_key}"

request = json.loads(requests.get(api_url).text)


print(request["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"])
```